# What are the legalities of web scraping in Pakistan?

Tags: internet, pakistan

I couldn't really find much useful info about it online. One thing that seems to be somewhat useful is [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/pakistan/comments/i3ux6j/is_data_gathering_or_data_scraping_illegal_from/) but it doesn't contain any sources.

Is web scraping legal in Pakistan? If yes, then to what extents?

Comment: Are you asking about web scraping sites in other countries *from* your location in Pakistan, or web scraping anything, either on sites in Pakistan or the rest of the world?

Comment: See https://law.stackexchange.com/search?q=web+scraping

Comment: @BlueDogRanch The latter. I am asking about the legality of people web scraping *from* Pakistan. Either nationally or internationally.

Answer (score -4):

To my knowledge, web scraping is a grey area without specific legislation addressing it. One way you could decide the legality is based on what data is scraped and how it's used.

Scraping data other than what is publicly available without appropriate consent, using it for harmful purposes, scraping anything that violates a site's Terms, or using it in any way that violates its Terms may be factors that may weighed against the use of scraping in a given instance.